# Is the intersection a line, plane or an empty set?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I'm wondering about a geometric interpretation of the equation system shown below:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=6\\
x_1+x_3+x_4=4\\
x_1+x_3 = 2$$
I've calculated the echelon form of those equations and got these results:
$$x_1 = 2- x_3\\x_2 = 2\\ x_3 = x_3 \\ x_4 = 2$$
I know that the system has infinitely many solutions. Can you explain me how to intuitively find out if the intersection is a line, plane or an empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, since the system has solutions (and even many of them!), you already know that its solution set is not empty.

To understand this solution set geometrically, note that it has one free variable in it, which effectively tells us that the solution set is one-dimensional. (I'm being a bit nor rigorous here, since this solution set is not a vector subspace; but it is an affine subspace, which is indeed one-dimensional.) So it's a line.

To actually see that this is a line, and more specifically what this line is, let's represent the solutions in vector form:
$$\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2-x_3 \\ 2 \\ x_3 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} -x_3 \\ 0 \\ x_3 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 0 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}+x_3\begin{bmatrix} -1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Now we can see that it's a line thru the point $(2,2,0,2)^T$ and parallel to the direction vector $(-1,0,1,0)^T$.

Answer (score 1):

$x_3=x_3$ means $x_3$ can be anything we like. $x_2$ and $x_4$ are constant, so we cant "move" along those axis. Now imagine sliding $x_3$ around. Think of it as an independent variable, if you like. $x_1$ is a line in terms of $x_3$, so the relationship between them will form a line in the $x_1 - x_3$ plane. Thus the solution set forms a line.